# How to add new line to itab with VALUE expression

Tags: abap

ABAP 7.40 brought us new syntax, I am still figuring it out.
I want to add a new line to the existing table `lt_itab`. I found a workaround by adding an empty line and figuring out the current length of the table for an update by index, but is there an easier way?

```
SELECT spfli~carrid, carrname, connid, cityfrom, cityto
  FROM scarr
  INNER JOIN spfli
  ON scarr~carrid = spfli~carrid
  WHERE scarr~carrid = @carrier
  ORDER BY scarr~carrid
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_itab).

"How can I simplify the following code part?" 
DATA(lv_idx) = lines( lt_itab ).
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_itab.
lt_itab[ lv_idx + 1 ] = VALUE #( carrid    = 'UA'
                                 carrname  = 'United Airlines'
                                 connid    = 941
                                 cityfrom  = 'Frankfurt'
                                 cityto    = 'San Francisco' ).
```

Comment: The solution of @Gert Beukema is maybe the most reasonable one. We only want to use the new features, in places where they are really useful. In your case they aren't so just use `APPEND`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It's all in the documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenvalue_constructor_params_itab.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@):

```
lt_itab = VALUE #( BASE lt_itab ( carrid = ... ) ).
```

Comment: Is the "BASE" really a keyword, which implies the source table and therefore automatically can deal with all table types ?

Comment: I do believe the documentation I linked to is relatively clear on that: _If BASE is specified, the content of stab is assigned to the return value before the individual rows are inserted._

Comment: My main focus was on the table types, i will read the doc in depth.

Answer (score 4):

The index logic is pretty ugly, you can easily use the `ASSIGNING` addition to the `APPEND` command to get a field symbol to the newly added line. You can then use that field symbol to fill the table entry using the same `VALUE` construct you are using now.

Or you can do it in one statement:

```
APPEND VALUE #( ... ) TO lt_itab.
```

Comment: In my test cases, this is also the fastest solution